# Lombok v1.18.12 is not working with Eclipse JEE 2019-12 release

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, lombok

**Description:**

1. Add Lombok dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <version>1.18.12</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

2. Start Lombok installation in `C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.12` and locate the path `D:\IDE+Editor\eclipse\eclipse.exe`
3. Move to Eclipse installation folder and run command `java -jar lombok.jar`, I got an exception:

```
D:\IDE+Editor\eclipse>java -jar lombok.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lombok.core.Main
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:718)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at lombok.launch.ShadowClassLoader.loadClass(ShadowClassLoader.java:534)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at lombok.launch.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

I restart my Eclipse but it cannot run until I delete the line `-javaagent:D:\IDE\+Editor\eclipse\lombok.jar` in `eclipse.ini`. After all, Lombok have not installed in my Eclipse.

**Version info:**

- java version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
- lombok v1.18.12
- eclipse jee 2019-12 R

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with lombok before you even involve Eclipse.

Comment: This guide may help.
https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/january-2010-reducing-boilerplate-code-with-project-lombok

Comment: @nitind yeah I think so. It seems many people have the same problem with Lombok 1.18.x

Comment: @user54321 thanks but it not work in my case

Comment: You could try downloading Lombok directly from https://projectlombok.org/. Maybe something is wrong with the jar downloaded from your maven repository.

Comment: @JanRieke thanks but I think that is not the problem. I have just changed the `IDE+Editor` folder name to `IDE` and the Lombok work perfectly. Maybe the '+' character make Lombok confused when locating Eclipse folder address.

Comment: Have you configured the eclipse.ini file correctly with Lombok?

Comment: @khmarbaise yeah, I think the '+' character in folder name make the eclipse.ini gone wrong, so I removed it

Comment: Sounds like this one: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1536

Comment: @JanRieke that's it

Comment: Instead of putting the answer into your question, you should answer your own question yourself. This is perfectly legitimate and the suggested way when you later find out the answer by yourself.

Comment: @JanRieke got it :P. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** My problem was resolved by removing the '+' character in `IDE+Editor` folder name and reinstalling Lombok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

This is a Lombok bug from version `1.18.12`.

The solution would be to update Lombok to `1.18.14` or higher.

The bug was described here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252069

> For anyone coming here, this was fixed as of Lombok 1.18.14

So just change `1.18.12` to `1.18.14` in `pom.xml`, reload `Maven` project and it will work.